# MongoDB aggregate elements of nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

We've got a MongoDB (v2.4) collection that contains time-series snapshots:

```
{"foo": "bar",
 "timeseries": [{"a": 1, "b": 2},
                {"a": 2, "b": 3},
                ...]}
{"foo": "baz",
 "timeseries": [{"a": 0, "b": 1},
                {"a": 2, "b": 3},
                ...]}
```

I need to group all the entries by the `foo` key, and then sum the the `a` values of the last entry in each of the `timeseries` values of each document (`timeseries[-1].a`, as it were), per key. I want to believe there's some combination of `$group`, `$project`, and `$unwind` that can do what I want without having to resort to `mapReduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something along the lines of:

```
> db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$timeseries"},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id", foo: {$last: "$foo"},
                         last_value: {$last: "$timeseries.a"}}},
  {$group: { _id: "$foo", total: { $sum: "$last_value" }}}
])
{ "_id" : "baz", "total" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "bar", "total" : 2 }
```

- the `$unwind` stage will produce one document per-item in the timeserie
- after that, documents are grouped back again, keeping only the [`$last`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) value
- finally, a second group clause will group (and sum values) by the *foo* field.

As a final note, I don't think this will be time efficient for very long time series as basically MongoDB will have to iterate over all items just in order to reach the last one.